# If $a_i$ is a basis does $\langle f, a_i \rangle =0$ for all $i$ mean that $f=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a set spanned by $a_1, .., a_n$ with an inner product $\langle , \rangle$. If for all $i$ $\langle f, a_i \rangle = 0$, then does it follow that $f=0$?

It's easy to prove this when the basis is orthonormal. How to do it otherwise? please no Gram-Schmidt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f=\sum_{j=1}^nf_ja_j$, then $||f||^2=\langle f,f \rangle=\langle f,\sum_{j=1}^nf_ja_j \rangle=\sum_{j=1}^nf_j \langle f,a_j \rangle=0$.

So $||f||=0$, which means that $f=0$.

Comment: For inner products in LaTeX you can use '\langle' and '\rangle' ($\langle f,f\rangle$) instead of the '<' and '>'.

Answer (score 0):

Does $f$ in A? If not $f$ is just orthogonal to A so not necessarily $f=0$.

If it is in A, then $f=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i a_i$ for some $c_i$ from the field. Then we have $\langle f,a_i \rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n c_i\langle a_j,a_i$ which is greater than zero since it has at least one $c_k \neq 0$ hence it has $c_k\langle a_k,a_k \rangle=c_k||a_k||^2 > 0$. Contradiction, so $f=0$ if $f\in A$